# linear congruences and range of solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

When studying Wilson's theorem in the proof I found that ax ≡ 1 (mod p), with 1 ≤ a ≤ p−1 and (a,p)=1 has a unique solution $a'$ in the range 1 ≤ a' < p. (Prop. 4.32 here https://gioretikto.github.io/mat/algebra/wilson.html)

I know the theorem governing the existence of solutions states that ax ≡ b (mod n), has solutions if and only if d = gcd(a, n) divides b and when d=1 the solution is unique. But this theorem doesn't say anything about the range of the solutions.

Why is the range of solutions restricted to 1 ≤ a' < p?

Comment: It has a unique solution modulo $p$, which implies that if you take any complete reduced residue system modulo $p$ it will have exactly one solution in that system. $\{\,1,2,\dots,p-1\,\}$ is just one convenient complete reduced residue system.

Comment: I don't understand well the relation between the residue system {1,2,…,p−1} which shoudl be $Z_p$ and the solutions of ax ≡ 1 (mod p)

Comment: The solution of $ax\equiv1\bmod p$ is a congruence class modulo $p$. That congruence class may be represented by any of its elements, which are integers. Every congruence class (except the class of zero, which has no relevance here) has a representative $b$ in the range $1\le b\le p-1$, and it is often convenient to take that representative, so it is in that sense the congruence has  its solution restricted to that range. So we might say, for example, that the solution of $2x\equiv1\bmod3$ is $x\equiv2\bmod3$. We could just as correctly say the solution is $x\equiv5\bmod3$ (continued)

Comment: (continued) or $x\equiv 29\bmod3$ or .... There's just something convenient about taking  the representative to be between $1$ and $p-1$.  Does this help?

Comment: It does a lot. I can replace one solution to another congruent to it mod n. So there is not a unique solution to the congruence 2x ≡ 1 (mod 3) but infinite e.g. x = 5, x = 8,  x = 11, x = 14,... So they all belong to $[2]_3$. Now any integer x is congruent to its remainder when divided by n and owning to the property of division in Z this is in the range 0<= r < n. The other question that arises at this point is: What's intended by "unique solution"?

Comment: (continued) I think it is the remainder $r$ in this case the range is [1, 2] but only 2 is a solution and 2 can be considered the unique solution?

Comment: There is a unique congruence class, what you have written as $[2]_3$. That's what's meant by unique solution; the solution isn't a number, it's a congruence class. Alternatively, if you restrict to the range $1\le x\le p-1$, then you can say there's a unique solution in that range; if you pick any complete reduced residue system, there's a unique solution in that system.

Comment: So, are we OK now?

Comment: Yes? No? Maybe?